# Looking for a Harry Potter fanfic where Severus lives and is in hiding

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Snarry fic I read some years ago I don't remember much from the fic but what I do recall is that Snape, who survived Nagini's attack went into hiding and that his injury to his neck was not healing. At some point Harry found him and convinced him to return to  Hogwarts to get help and Snape agreed to go back with him, I think also that Hermione was a teacher or something at Hogwarts and she was having problems with some of her paperwork frustrated she goes to bed and the next day when she goes back to her work some of it has been done for her. That's all that I remember thanks for the help.

Update: just remembered that no one knows Severus is alive in this fic.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gotten far enough to be certain, but this might be [Educating Elena](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11722985/1/Educating-Elena) by Catia2005. It opens with Snape hiding in a dodgy apartment complex named Spinner's End. Snape has the neck injury that isn't healing right, and he eventually does go back to Hogwarts. Right now, I'm at the part where he's provided a palliative for Alzheimer's to his neighbor, Elena, and we've learned that she has some magic ability.

> Severus Snape survived the war and Nagini's bite. He's seriously pissed off about it and lying low at Spinner's End, fearing retribution and the dragging-out-into-the-open of his private life. Until, one day, there is a knock on the door …

Comment: Thanks for the new read but that's not it in this one no one knows Severus is alive and there is nothing about a neighbor in it and I think it was on AO3.